# Dense layer: how to transform hgih dim vector to one dim? (sigmoid function)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a dense layer who transforms a 100 dimensional vector to a 1 dimensional object using a sigmoid function. I understand how a sigmoid function transforms a number to a number between 0 and 1.

But I don't understand how it transforms the dimensionality of the vectors?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest watching 3blue1brown's [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aircAruvnKk) series on neural networks to get a better conceptual understanding of what's going on.

It's not that the sigmoid function itself transforms the dimension of a vector - the sigmoid function is just used as an activation function that affects the output of **each individual node** - it's the number of units/nodes you have in a layer that does what you're describing.

If you only have one unit in your output layer it will only output one number between 0 and 1. If you have 100 units in a dense layer it will output 100 numbers, each between 0 and 1.

Comment: thanks! I got it! So the 1 in "model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))" makes sure there's only one node?

Comment: the sigmoid function transforms the content of the 100 nodes of the previous layer to a result between 0 and 1? How are these transformed to 1 node?

Comment: by the sigmoid function with all the weights of the previous nodes to the node of the dense layer?

Comment: @belgiums If you specify a layer to have only one node, then there were be only one node, no matter how many nodes the previous layer had. The sigmoid function only affects the output of each individual node.I think your understanding could use some improvement, I highly highly recommend checking out the YouTube series I linked, I think it will help you gain some clarity on this

Answer (score 0):

Don't think about each layer performing a dimension transformation on your data. If your input is 20-dimensional and your network structure is composed of a input layer, a 100-dimensional hidden layer and a 1-dimension output layer like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

# Define the neural network using Sequential
model = Sequential([
    Dense(100, input_dim=20, activation='relu'), # Input layer with 20 inputs and hidden layer with 100 neurons
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')               # Output layer with 1 neuron and sigmoid activation function
])
```

The first layer just receives the input and the second layer is of dimension 100. But note that this dimension transform is actually not made "in a layer" but in between the layers. This is performed by a simple matrix (of dimension 20x100 in this case) multiplication.

The activation function is only applied after the matrix multiplication. So we could write this neural net mathematically:

$x \in \mathbb{R}^{20}$

$y_1 = Relu(W_1.x) \quad ; \quad W_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{100 \times 20}$

$y_2 = Simoid(W_2.y_2) \quad ; \quad W_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 100}$

Where $W_1, W_2$ matrices represend the layers steps and $y_2$ would be the final output.